# The import x.x.x cannot be resolved with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I have a project that exports a package for another project to import and utilize. Within Eclipse, it seems to resolve correctly. But when building with Maven, I get the following errors: `The import x.x.x cannot be resolved`. I've fiddled around with the manifest/ pom.xml and restarted Eclipse several times and the results are the same.

The general structure is:

```
com.my.company.plugin
- com.my.company.pkg
```

And within that manifest.mf, I have `Export-Package: com.my.company.pkg`

For the other plugin's manifest, I have `Require-Bundle: com.my.company.pkg;resolution:=optional` (I've tried taking the option portion out, but that didn't seem to matter)

And within the source for the second plugin, I have:

```
import com.my.company.pkg.MyClass

public class MyOtherClass implements MyClass {
```

Locally in Eclipse it all works fine. But when I try to build with Maven, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]     import com.my.company.pkg.MyClass;
[ERROR]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import com.my.company.pkg cannot be resolved

[ERROR]     public class MyOtherClass implements MyClass {
[ERROR]                                          ^^^^^^^
[ERROR] MyClass cannot be resolved to a type
```

The strange thing is that I have other imports within MyOtherClass that reference other plugins and added in the `Required-Bundles`. I'm guessing it's how I'm exporting the first plugin. What exactly am I missing?

---EDIT---

It seems like adding this block in the parent pom is causing it to fail. Which is odd because I thought it by setting it to `ignore` it will completely ignore the optional dependencies instead of trying to resolve it? While taking it out causes other areas that uses optional dependencies to fail...

```
<dependency-resolution>
    <optionalDependencies>ignore</optionalDependencies>
    <extraRequirements>
        <requirement>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
            <id>org.eclipse.ui</id>
            <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
        </requirement>
        <requirement>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
            <id>org.eclipse.ui.views</id>
            <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
        </requirement>
    </extraRequirements>
</dependency-resolution>
```